# How to compute the derivative of $\frac{\partial AB^T }{\partial{A}}$ and $\frac{\partial AB^T }{\partial{B}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

How to compute the derivative of $$\frac{\partial AB^T }{\partial{A}}$$ and $$\frac{\partial AB^T }{\partial{B}}$$

where $A \in R^{m \times n}$ and $B \in R^{r \times n}$.

Also, how can we analysis the dimension of final result? such as $\frac{\partial AB^T }{\partial{A}}$ is a matrix or tensor?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It will be 4th order tensor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the function using index notation (with the summation convention).
$$\eqalign{
F_{ik} &= A_{ij} B_{jk}^T = A_{ij} B_{kj} \\
dF_{ik} &= dA_{ij}\,B_{kj} + A_{ij}\,dB_{kj} \\
}$$
Holding $B$ constant (i.e. $dB_{kj}=0$) yields the derivative with respect to $A$.
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial F_{ik}}{\partial A_{pq}}
 &= (\delta_{ip}\delta_{jq})\,B_{kj} = \delta_{ip}\,B_{kq} \\
}$$
Similarly holding $A$ constant yields the derivative with respect to $B$.
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial F_{ik}}{\partial B_{pq}}
 &= A_{ij}\,(\delta_{kp}\delta_{jq}) = A_{iq}\,\delta_{kp} \\
}$$
These derivatives require 4 indices for their description. So they are not matrices but 4th order tensors.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use vectorizations,

Let

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
C & = AB^T \\
dC & = (dA)B^T + A(dB^T) \\
vec(dC) & = \text{vec}(dAB^T) + \text{vec}(AdB^T) \\
& = (B \otimes I)\text{vec}(dA) + (I \otimes A)\text{vec}(dB^T) \\
& = (B \otimes I)\text{vec}(dA) + (I \otimes A)K\text{vec}(dB) \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Then

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\text{vec}(dC)}{\text{vec}(dA)} & = (B \otimes I) \\
\frac{\text{vec}(dC)}{\text{vec}(dB)} & = (I \otimes A)K \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where $K$ is the Kronecker commutation matrix.